# Is it possible to transfer NFC data from one Android device to another device bypasing android beam?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I am trying to send NFC data from one Android device to another. I was able to do it successfully using the Andoid Beam functionality. But I would like the data transfer to take place automatically (bypassing Android Beam) as soon as both the devices are together.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making NFC/Beam more automatic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542697/making-nfc-beam-more-automatic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of your device have Android KitKat (4.4), there's a new feature in this version:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html

You could put one device in reader mode (default mode) and one device in card mode (card emulation).

Comment: then, without HCE and Beam UI touch, is there any way to transfer simple data between NFC enabled mobile with another same mobile like 4.4 and above ? enableForegroundDispatch , enableForegroundNdefPush , setNdefPushMessage. am using this methods for trying for the above.

Comment: It's not possible 2 readers cannot communicate. You have to convert a reader in card emulation mode